# cant start my rails server [linux]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-4, server

When running the rails server command from the directory that contains my app i get this error message:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2018-05-28 15:55:12] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2018-05-28 15:55:12] INFO  ruby 2.3.1 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
Exiting
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:231:in `getaddrinfo': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:231:in `foreach'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:757:in `tcp_server_sockets'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/utils.rb:65:in `create_listeners'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:134:in `listen'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:115:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:47:in `initialize'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.10/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:31:in `new'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.10/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:31:in `run'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.10/lib/rack/server.rb:287:in `start'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/jack/Desktop/Rails/MegsBlog/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It prohibits it for good reasons! Can you provide more information? (initializers, database.yml, WEBrick config) any kind of information that you feel is relevant.

Comment: The "disregard"-edit, what shall it mean? Should we delete this question?

Comment: Let's give them a chance to fix the question. Can you add the command that you used to run this?

Comment: the disregard is there to tell you to ignore all of the text after it as its only purpose is to allow me to post this question with this little info

Comment: i used the "rails server" command

Comment: im using webrick 1.3.1 and ruby 2.3.1 if that helps

Comment: Do you have `localhost` entry in your hosts file?
The question was [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768934/rails-server-cannot-start-getaddrinfo-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-k)

Comment: what does that mean

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `127.0.0.1 localhost` to your `/etc/hosts` file. Also always run the `rails server` command using `bundle` -> `bundle exec rails server`.