# Error while executing rails application with action cable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

**This is my error:**

```
<Thread:0x00007fde3dc23378@/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actioncable-5.2.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:148 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    26: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actioncable-5.2.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:152:in `block in ensure_listener_running'
    25: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actioncable-5.2.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:78:in `listen'
    24: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis.rb:70:in `without_reconnect'
    23: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis.rb:63:in `with_reconnect'
    22: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis.rb:58:in `synchronize'
    21: from /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
    20: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis.rb:58:in `block in synchronize'
    19: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis.rb:64:in `block in with_reconnect'
    18: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis/client.rb:293:in `with_reconnect'
    17: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actioncable-5.2.3/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:81:in `block in listen'
    16: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis.rb:2142:in `subscribe'
    15: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis.rb:58:in `synchronize'
    14: from /.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
    13: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis.rb:58:in `block in synchronize'
    12: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis.rb:2143:in `block in subscribe'
    11: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis.rb:2775:in `_subscription'
    10: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:12:in `subscribe'
     9: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb:43:in `subscription'
     8: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis/client.rb:133:in `call_loop'
     7: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis/client.rb:276:in `with_socket_timeout'
     6: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis/client.rb:100:in `connect'
     5: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis/client.rb:293:in `with_reconnect'
     4: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis/client.rb:101:in `block in connect'
     3: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis/client.rb:336:in `establish_connection'
     2: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:313:in `connect'
     1: from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:229:in `connect'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-3.3.5/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:229:in **`getaddrinfo': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)**
Exiting
```

I have tried https://medium.com/rubyinside/action-cable-hello-world-with-rails-5-1-efc475b0208b

Comment: check this links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132525/getaddrinfo-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768934/rails-server-cannot-start-getaddrinfo-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-k

Comment: What is the value of host you provided?. It looks like your host configuration is wrong.

Comment: In which file we give host configuration?

Comment: did you solved this issue?